# в mysql для быстрого поиска по дате лучше использовать timestamp как int или как date (datetime)

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

в mysql для быстрого поиска по дате лучше использовать timestamp как int или как  date (datetime)?

Comment: лучше использовать datetime

Comment: При наличии индекса по полю поиска `WHERE datetime_column = 'datetime value'` медленнее, чем `WHERE int_column = UNIX_TIMESTAMP('datetime value')`. Причина проста - DATETIME занимает 8 байтов, а INT - 4 байта, т.е. тупо размер индекса и, соответственно, количество дисковых операций, различно.  Если же индекс "горячий", то разницу определить не удастся. Вот в паре TIMESTAMP(0) - INT скорость по-любому одинакова (оба типа занимают 4 байта).

Answer (score 0):

TIMESTAMP — тип данных для хранения даты и времени. Данные хранятся в виде количества секунд, прошедших с начала «эпохи Юникса». Диапазон значений: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 — 2038-12-31 00:00:00. Занимает 4 байта.

YEAR — тип данных для хранения года. Диапазон значений: 1901 — 2155. Занимает 1 байт.

DATE — тип данных для хранения даты. Диапазон значений: 1000-01-01 — 9999-12-31. Занимает 3 байта.

TIME — тип данных для хранения времени. Диапазон значений: −828:59:59 — 828:59:59. Занимает 3 байта.

DATETIME — тип данных для хранения даты и времени. Диапазон значений: 1000-01-01 00:00:00 — 9999-12-31 00:00:00. Занимает 8 байт.

Comment: разве это отвечает на ваш вопрос?